# Error git publickey

Tags: git, github, git-push

Cuando intento dar git push a cualquier proyecto sea nuevo o viejo me aparece esto

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.113)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
```

Me dicen que tengo que crear una publickey, pero no hay una forma de eliminar eso de mi cuenta de github? Cada vez que estoy en otro pc me aparece esto.

Answer (score 0):

Es algo normal, cuando ssh intenta conectarse a un host que no ha visto antes te mostrara dicho mensaje, para solucionarlo simplemente haz uso de la siguiente linea:

`ssh -T git@github.com`

y si no funciona siempre puedes intentar este otro metodo:

`ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo el error